Как включить опцию "Ненадежные приложения, у которых есть доступ к аккаунту"
сам гугл пишет "Эта настройка недоступна в вашем аккаунте." мне это нужно, чтобы отправлять электронные письма с помощью C#, но встала такая проблема

А вы какой пароль используете? Пароль приложения или аккаунта?

Где именно? И пароль какого приложения?

Ну, я так понимаю вы хотите использовать GMail аккаунт для отправки через C# код писем, соответственно вы вводите данные этого аккаунта, так? Если да, то GMail требует пароль приложения, которое вы создаете в своем аккаунте и который вам генерирует система. И только связка ваш логин + пароль приложения позволит вам автоматизировать отправку писем. Если я не так понял вопрос, тогда давайте больше деталей, ибо не до конца понятно что вы хотите и как вы получаете данную ошибку.

Что такое «Ошибка молотка» или «Ошибка XY»?

хорошо, я все понял
